# How can I stack shapes using recursion in scheme?

Tags: recursion, scheme, shapes

I am trying to use recursion to stack a basic shape I created earlier (y) on top of itself x times.

```
(define stack-copies-of
   (lambda (x y)
     (if zero? x) 
         null
         (if > x 0) 
             (stack-copies-of (- x 1))))
```

How do I get it do keep displaying shapes on top of each other then stop at 0?

Comment: Your function takes two parameters but you send recursively only one... you probably want to do something like: `(stack-copies-of (- x 1) (cons (car y) y))` and start calling it with the number you want and `(cons y null)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "stack a basic shape" you mean to build a stack (a list) using recursion, then this will work for you:

```
(define stack-copies-of
  ; y is a shape, x is a number of shapes
  (lambda (x y)
    ; for zero or negative number of shapes, return the empty list
    (if (<= x 0) '()
    ; for more than zero shapes, use recursion to build a list
                 (cons y (stack-copies-of (sub1 x)))
    )))
```

If you wish to use actually display shapes on the screen, then more clarification is needed.

Comment: I want to display a stack of shapes on the screen x in length. Sorry about not specifying that.